# displaying the pdf file in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

Hi I am new to django framework when the user click i need to display the pdf file 
the code i am using is

```
with open(file_path+file_name, 'rb') as pdf:
    response = HttpResponse(pdf.read(), mimetype='application/pdf', contenttype='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline;filename=some_file.pdf'
```

error i am getting is

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 90, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 489, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 449, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 486, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/tritwdapp/tribalwelfare/inspection/inspectdataview.py", line 290, in getSubmitReport
    response = HttpResponse(pdf.read(), mimetype='application/pdf',contenttype='application/pdf')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/http/response.py", line 283, in __init__
    super(HttpResponse, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'contenttype'
```

can any one please help me

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
def pdf_view(request):
    with open('file.pdf', 'r') as pdf:
        response = HttpResponse(pdf.read(), content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline;filename=some_file.pdf'
        return response
```

[`mimetype`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-1-7) has been replaced by [`content_type`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.content_type). It was removed in `Django 1.7`. Additionally, you are spelling it wrong.
Be aware that such a solution isn't optimal. Normally your web server would serve those files for performance reasons.